# Commit -S unknown switch `S'

Tags: github

I followed doc https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits/
I run commands to add gpg signature.

Once I try to commit the change

```
git commit -S -m your commit message
```

I am getting this error:

```
 error: unknown switch `S'
```

Which result in:

```
remote: Commit 96e398fb3493 was not signed by a GPG key, rejecting push
```

I have another repo where I did not have that problem and everything works fine.

I would be grateful for any ideas

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you checked the tips from your link?
Have you done the git config commit for the signature for this repo?
You should also check the signature : git tag -v .
More details you can find on the following link: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work?fbclid=IwAR1z43ofPeEx3sWliKj4aPV6XnzsAdNtV5wF86mzLC1SsIcaaTsViJsH_So .